# Applicative typeclass based on two different functors

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

Is there something similar to the `Applicative` type class, but where there are two functors for each side of the application which are different?

i.e. `(<*>) :: (Functor f, Functor g) => f (a -> b) -> g a -> f b`

Comment: Are there specific concrete types that you're looking to use this with? This function can't be derived for just any two functors.

Comment: Or any two applicatives.

Comment: @4castle: Sorry I didn't think things through well enough. I'm looking for a generalized zip that can handle and convert different sequence types automatically.

Comment: I think you would need to provide the natural transformation from one functor to the other yourself; even assuming you can get the function out of the applicative `f` and apply it to the `g a` to get a `g b`, you still need something with type `g b -> f b` to get your final result.

Comment: (Probably *two* natural transformations, the other to get a `g (a -> b)` from `f (a -> b)` in the first place.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Following a suggestion from @dfeuer in the comments.)

There is a construction called [day convolution](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2/docs/Data-Functor-Day.html) that lets you preserve the distinction between two functors when performing applicative operations, and delay the moment of transforming one into the other.

The [`Day`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2/docs/Data-Functor-Day.html#t:Day) type is simply a pair of functorial values, together with a function that combines their respective results:

```
data Day f g a = forall b c. Day (f b) (g c) (b -> c -> a)
```

Notice that the actual return values of the functors are existencialized; the return value of the composition is that of the function.

`Day` has advantages over other ways of combining applicative functors. Unlike [`Sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Sum.html), the composition is still applicative. Unlike [`Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html), the composition is "unbiased" and doesn't impose a nesting order. Unlike [`Product`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html), it lets us easily combine applicative actions with *different* return types, we just need to provide a suitable adapter function.

For example, here are two `Day ZipList (Vec Nat2) Char` values:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
import           Data.Functor.Day -- from "kan-extensions"
import           Data.Type.Nat -- from "fin"
import           Data.Vec.Lazy -- from "vec"
import           Control.Applicative

day1 :: Day ZipList (Vec Nat2) Char
day1 = Day (pure ()) ('b' ::: 'a' ::: VNil) (flip const)

day2 :: Day ZipList (Vec Nat2) Char
day2 = Day (ZipList "foo") (pure ()) const
```

([`Nat2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fin-0.0.1/docs/Data-Type-Nat.html#t:Nat2) is from the [fin](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fin-0.0.1/docs/Data-Type-Nat.html) package, it is used to parameterize a fixed-size `Vec` from [vec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vec-0.1/docs/Data-Vec-Lazy.html).)

We can zip them together just fine:

```
res :: Day ZipList (Vec Nat2) (Char,Char)
res = (,) <$> day1 <*> day2
```

And then transform the `Vec` into a `ZipList` and collapse the `Day`:

```
res' :: ZipList (Char,Char)
res' = dap $ trans2 (ZipList . toList) res

ghci> res'
ZipList {getZipList = [('b','f'),('a','o')]}
```

Using the [`dap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2/docs/Data-Functor-Day.html#v:dap) and [`trans2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2/docs/Data-Functor-Day.html#v:trans2) functions.

Possible performance catch: when we lift one of the functors to `Day`, the other is given a dummy `pure ()` value. But this is dead weight when combining `Day`s with `(<*>)`. One can work smarter by wrapping the functors in [`Lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Applicative-Lift.html) for transformers, to get faster operations for the simple "pure" cases.

Comment: A practical example of `Day`: my "process-streaming" library uses `Day` internally to combine handlers for the stdin, stdout and stderr of an external process into a single `Applicative`. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-streaming-0.9.3.0/docs/System-Process-Streaming.html#t:Streams It also uses the `Lift` trick.

Answer (score 2):

One general concept of "sequence type" is a free monoid. Since you're looking at polymorphic sequence types, we can build on `Traversable`.

```
class Semigroup1 t where
  (<=>) :: t a -> t a -> t a

class Semigroup1 t => Monoid1 t where
  mempty1 :: t a
```

See note below.

```
class (Traversable t, Monoid1 t) => Sequence t where
  singleton :: a -> t a
```

How is that a sequence type? Very inefficiently. But we could add a bunch of methods with default implementations to make it efficient. Here are some basic functions:

```
cons :: Sequence t => a -> t a -> t a
cons x xs = singleton x <=> xs

fromList
  :: (Foldable f, Sequence t)
  => f a -> t a
fromList = foldr cons mempty1

uncons :: Sequence t => t a -> Maybe (a, t a)
uncons xs = case toList xs of
  y:ys -> Just (y, fromList ys)
  [] -> Nothing
```

With these tools, you can zip any two sequences to make a third.

```
zipApp :: (Foldable t, Foldable u, Sequence v) = t (a -> b) -> u a -> v b
zipApp fs xs = fromList $ zipWith ($) (toList fs) (toList xs)
```

---

#### Note on recent GHC versions

For bleeding edge GHC, you can use `QuantifiedConstraints` and `RankNTypes` and `ConstraintKinds` and define

```
type Semigroup1 t = forall a. Semigroup (t a)

type Monoid1 t = forall a. Monoid (t a)
```

Doing it this way would let you write, e.g.,

```
fromList = foldMap singleton
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I think you might be trying to construct:

```
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable
foo :: (Traversable f, Foldable g) => f (a -> b) -> g a -> f b
foo f g = snd $ mapAccumR (\(a:as) fab -> (as, fab a)) (toList g) f
```

This allows, for example:

```
> import qualified Data.Vector as V
> foo [(+1),(+2),(+3)] (V.fromList [5,6,7])
[8,8,8]
>
```

Comment: `foo [(+1),(+2),(+3)] (V.fromList [5,6,7,8])` works, `foo [(+1),(+2),(+3)] (V.fromList [5,6])` bombs with `"Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda"`.

Comment: Yes, I was aware the function was partial, but I don't think there's a clear alternative.  You could `cycle` the list from `g`, which seems like a terrible idea, or you could restrict the function to `f` that are isomorphic to `[]` (e.g., use constraint `IsList f`).

Answer (score 0):

<del>I don't know of any general `fromList`.</del>  I would write the concrete version, or at most generalize over the input types.  Here are examples with `Vector`, ignoring that `Data.Vector.zip` already exists.

```hs
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector (Vector)
import Data.Foldable
import GHC.Exts (IsList(fromList))

zipV1 :: Vector (a -> b) -> Vector a -> Vector b
zipV1 fs as = V.fromList (zipWith ($) (V.toList fs) (V.toList as))

zipV2 :: (Foldable f, Foldable g, IsList (f b)) => f (a -> b) -> g a -> f b
zipV2 fs as = fromList (zipWith ($) (toList fs) (toList as))
```

You could use `IsList` instead of `Foldable` in the second example.

Comment: Note that there is `fromList` from `IsList`, so that would work, and many standard list-isomorphic sequences will support it (e.g., `Vector` already as an instance).